# Syncing Notes with Gmail & iCloud

Tags: data-synchronization, macos, gmail, notes.app

In the `Mail, Contacts & Calendars` Preference pane, you can have `Notes` synchronize with a Gmail account. 
I've already got it setup to work nicely with iCloud, but..
Where do I go in Gmail to read these Notes? They don't appear under the "notes" label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your notes can synchronize with Gmail or iCloud, not both as far as I can tell.

To sync a note with Gmail do the following

1. Set up your account and check the notes box in the Mail, Contacts & Calendars preference pane.
2. Go to notes in Mountain Lion
3. Go to View -> Show Folders List -- or -- click the folders list icon in the bottom left side of the Notes window
4. From here you should be able to select your Gmail account instead of iCloud and create a new note
5. Within Gmail you should have a folder called "Notes" and your newly created note should be inside